# What exactly causes mechanical waves?

Tags: waves

I agree its all about vibrations the energy causes the medium to vibrate and the total over all displacement of matter is 0, but how exactly are ripples formed?

I read that a vibrating particle can push or pull the water molecules and later that water molecule pull or pushes the other water particle. How does that exactly happen?

Kindly enphasize on water waves.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, a mechanical wave is unable to propagate through a vacuum, unlike electromagnetic waves, which do not require a medium, and *can* propagate through a vacuum. A wave, as you probably know, simply carries energy through a medium, and does not move the medium itself. Similarly, in the case of water waves, there is no overall displacement of matter, as you mentioned. When there occurs a disturbance in the body of water, which is the medium, water is pushed outwards, thereby creating what you refer to as “ripples”. There is no movement of water involved, there is just energy being moved through the water. At its most fundamental level, ${\text{H}_2\text{O}}$ molecules collide with each other, resulting in the ripple.

Comment: This is correct when it comes to water waves. The wave moves through but the water molecules stay in their general area. On the other hand, a light wave is made of billions of coherent photons that DO move through space.